# Raspbian: Enable/disable OverlayFS from terminal?

Tags: raspbian

I know that I can enable/disable OverlayFS from the raspi-config, but do I do this from the terminal? Via a bash script for example.

Answer (score 5):

`sudo raspi-config nonint enable_overlayfs`
or
`sudo raspi-config nonint disable_overlayfs`

Then reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Just study `raspi-config` which is just a simple (if rather long) shell script and extract the bits you need.

It is actually possible to call the functions in `raspi-config`.

`enable_overlayfs()` `disable_overlayfs()` should work (but I have not tried).